# Combining the data of 3 tables

Tags: python, database, loops

I am working on a database for my neuronal network. Therefore I need to combine the data of 3 different tables. The information in those tables is as follows.

Table 1: name of picture, additional data(2 columns)
Table 2: name of picture, name of machine, timestamp 1
Table 3: name of machine, timestamp 2, additional prozess info(7 columns)

For my database I need to have a table including: additional data(2 columns), additional prozess info(7 columns). All other Informations are not neccessary but it would be nice to save them in the table too.

I was trying to solve my problem with loops, I didnt manage to find the right code tho.
My idea is to first combine first and second table by comparing "name of picture" and afterwards add the third one by comparing "name of machine" and "timestamp".

I am glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are these 3 tables in a sql database? Then use the SQL `join` to combine their rows. You can even write that data to a new table, or just keep the `join` as a `view` and re-run it as needed. If I misunderstood your question, please [edit] it to be more specific. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: For now they are in .csv so it shouldnt be a problem to transfer into sql. Thank you for the idea, Ive never used SQL but Im going to try it!